# No of computation in the process of applying Low pass filter(AxB) on Image having dimension NxM

Tags: image-processing, lowpass-filter

I am willing to calculate no of computation in the process of applying Low pass filter(AxB) on Image having dimension NxM.

Can anyone please help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many methods to do this, since convolution to Fourier analysis among others.

If you wants to do a convolution you have to run over the image I(mn) with a mask M(AB).
considering that you only run over internal parts of the image you will do (N-A)*(M-B)*(A*B*2) operation approximately.

Fourier filtering I have to take a look better but in bigger images is much more efficient.